# Joining two tables in SQL while checking conditions

Tags: mysql

In my `ClassicModels.OrderDetails` table it has a `ProductCode` and `QuantityOrdered`

In my `ClassicModels.Products` table it has a `ProductLine` and `ProductCode`

Now, I need to write a SQL query that finds any product lines that have not been ordered

Here is my code but it is not letting me run it, and I cannot figure out why.

```
Select ProductLine from ClassicModels.Products
    group by ProductLine
join
ClassicModels.OrderDetails
    on ProductCode = ProductCode
    having count(QuantityOrdered) > 0
```

Comment: Your syntax isn't valid: `select ... from ... join ... group by ... having ...`  Also you'll need to alias your fields in the `select` and `on` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

The `join` clause should come straight after the `from` clause, before the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   ProductLine
FROM     ClassicModels.Products
JOIN     ClassicModels.OrderDetails ON ProductCode = ProductCode -- clause moved
GROUP BY ProductLine
HAVING   COUNT(QuantityOrdered) > 0
```